# Mocked class and methods not being patched

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I have a file, main.py, which contains one method, main():

```
from grab_api_tokens import GrabApiTokens

def main()
    grab_api_tokens = GrabApiTokens(site_one, site_two)
    site_one_token = grab_api_tokens.login_to_site_one
    site_two_token = grab_api_tokens.login_to_site_two
```

When trying to test this, I'm using:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch, Mock
import main

class TestMain(unittest.TestCase):
@patch('main.grab_apitokens.GrabApiTokens.login_to_site_two')
@patch('main.grab_apitokens.GrabApiTokens.login_to_site_one')
@patch('main.grab_apitokens.GrabApiTokens')
def test_main(self, mock_grab_api_tokens, mock_login_to_site_one, mock_login_to_site_two):
    mock_grab_api_tokens = Mock(ok=True)
    mock_login_to_site_one.return_value = "fake_token_one"
    mock_login_to_site_two.return_value = "fake_token_two"
    main.main()
    self.assertTrue(mock_grab_api_tokens.called)
```

the problem is that no matter how I change the @patch, I can't seem to get pycharm to recognize the mocked class. Calling main() just calls the plain main method, its not patching over the values I'm specifying. I can't see where I've gone wrong after reading the unittest documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The target you try to patch is not correct. Besides, you don't need to patch the properties of the `GrabApiTokens` class. You can patch the `GrabApiTokens` class and assign the fake data to the properties of its instance directly.

E.g.

`main.py`:

```py
from grab_api_tokens import GrabApiTokens


def main():
    site_one = '123'
    site_two = '456'
    grab_api_tokens = GrabApiTokens(site_one, site_two)
    site_one_token = grab_api_tokens.login_to_site_one
    site_two_token = grab_api_tokens.login_to_site_two
    print('site_one_token: ', site_one_token)
    print('site_two_token: ', site_two_token)
```

`grab_api_tokens.py`:

```py
class GrabApiTokens():
    def __init__(self, site_one, site_two) -> None:
        self.login_to_site_one = site_one
        self.login_to_site_two = site_two
```

`test_main.py`:

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch, Mock
import main


class TestMain(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('main.GrabApiTokens')
    def test_main(self, mock_grab_api_tokens):
        mock_instance = mock_grab_api_tokens.return_value
        mock_instance.login_to_site_one = "fake_token_one"
        mock_instance.login_to_site_two = "fake_token_two"
        main.main()
        self.assertTrue(mock_grab_api_tokens.called)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

test result:

```
 ⚡  coverage run /Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/python-codelab/src/stackoverflow/66641783/test_main.py && coverage report -m --include="src/*"
site_one_token:  fake_token_one
site_two_token:  fake_token_two
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
Name                                            Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
src/stackoverflow/66641783/grab_api_tokens.py       4      2    50%   3-4
src/stackoverflow/66641783/main.py                  9      0   100%
src/stackoverflow/66641783/test_main.py            13      0   100%
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL
```